# Recursive Binary Search for a 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, search, binary, 2d

I have been tasked with creating the recursive 2d binary search function, given a sorted 2d array.
It must be exactly as if its a 1d array, same principles:
Will check the middle of the array first (if its 3x3, the index 1,1 will be checked first
And continue from there as usual.
Appreciate the help.
The only clue that was said to me is to treat it as if its a 1D array, without actually converting it to a 1d array.

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static boolean binSearch(int[][] arr, int low, int high, int search) {
    if(low>high)
        return false;
    int avg=(low+high)/2;
    int i=(avg)/arr.length;
    int j=(avg)%arr[0].length;
    if(arr[i][j]==search)
        return true;
    if(arr[i][j]<search) 
        return binSearch(arr, avg+1, high, search);
    if(arr[i][j]>search)
        return binSearch(arr, low, avg-1, search);
    return false;
}
public static boolean binSearch(int[][] arr, int search) {
    return(binSearch(arr, 0, (arr.length*arr[0].length)-1, search));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr= {{1,2,3},
                  {4,5,6}}; 
    int search=4;
    System.out.println(binSearch(arr, search));
}
```

I feel like i'm close, but not quite there.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int numberToSearch = 4;
    int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},
                     {4,5,6}}; 
    int matrixSize = matrix.length * matrix[0].length - 1;

   System.out.println(binSearch(matrix, 0, matrixSize, numberToSearch));
}

public static boolean binSearch(int[][] i_matrix, int i_low, int i_high, int i_numberToSearch)
{
    if (i_low <= i_high)
    {
        int matrixWidth = i_matrix[0].length;
        int mid = (i_low + i_high) / 2;
        int currentCheckedNumber = i_matrix[mid / matrixWidth][mid % matrixWidth];

        if (currentCheckedNumber == i_numberToSearch)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (currentCheckedNumber < i_numberToSearch)
        {
            return binSearch(i_matrix, (mid + 1), i_high, i_numberToSearch);
        }
        else // if (currentCheckedNumber > i_numberToSearch)
        {
            return binSearch(i_matrix, i_low, (mid - 1), i_numberToSearch);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```